# mvc4 email validation localized error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I cannot localize the error message, if an email-address is the wrong format.

I keep getting the english message: "Please enter a valid email address"

this is my model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ihre Email-Adresse fehlt!")]
    [Display(Name = "Ihre Email Adresse")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Ungültige Email-Adresse")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Ungültige Email-Adresse")]
    public string From { get; set; }
```

the german message appears, if NO address is entered, but if an invalid one is entered, the english message appears.

As you can see, I tried both - ErrorMessage in DataType and in a RegularExpression-Annotation.

How can I present a localized ErrorMessage when address is invalid?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MVC doesn't do any validation of email addresses when using the DataTypeAttribute, therefore any error message you are seeing is either from the regular expression, or code from somewhere else.

Since you have an error message for failure of the regular expression, then it must be coming from something else.  Are you using any kind of third party validation tool for email addresses?  Since you're using the DataType attribute, is there a custom DisplayTemplate?

If you are using .net 4.5 (VS 2012) I would suggest using the EmailAddressAttribute instead:

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "...")]
```

With this, you remove the DataType (EmailAddress includes DataType functionality as it's derived from DataTypeAttribute) and the Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Mystere Man had the correct answer:

I was using jquery-validate, so I had to include the localization file for _de

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="localization/messages_de.js"></script>
```

which can be found at https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/localization